# How to instantiate Swift object from a string created at runtime?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

There are many case in objectiveC libraries that instantiate an object based on the name (String representation) of its class.

I have gotten very close with the following working code:

```
class Person{
    var age:Int = 1

    //somehow this is critical
    required init () {
    }
}

class Dog{
    var color:String = "Blue"

    //somehow this is critical
    required init () {
    }
}

/*
The basics
*/

let X = Person.self
var p1 = X()
p1.age = 5
println(p1.age)


/*
Instantiate from a String
*/
var hash1 = ["person":Person.self]

if let t = hash1["person"]{
    let p2 = t()
    p2.age = 8
    println(p2.age)
}
```

That last snippet with the dictionary is getting close to what a real-world implementation should look like except that we need to be able to put more than one Type into the dictionary; discern between the two and instantiate from the result. Something like the following non-working code:

```
var hash2 = ["dog":Dog.self, "person":Person.self] // needed for real-world usage
if let t2 = hash2["person"]{ // warning
    let p3 = t2()   //error
    p3.age = 11
    println(p3.age)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See, Swift is very type-safe language. So when you mess any different type, it's better to say to compiler what we are going to mess.
So `hash2` line will look like this:

```
var hash2: [String: Any] = ["dog": Dog.self, "person": Person.self]'
```

Here you just say, that dictionary will be with keys type of string and values with Any type (AnyObject goes from NSObject in Obj-c and here any type, because Dog.self and Person.self doesn't goes from obj-c and not the same type)

Then, while unwrapping, you need to say what type it will be, so next code will be like this:

```
if let t2 = hash2["person"] as? Person.Type {
    let p3 = t2() 
    p3.age = 11
    println(p3.age)
}
```

Here I just try not only to get key from dictionary, but to cast it for `Person.Type` type. Becouse value can be `Any` type as I mention while dictionary was decelerating and I need to cast it to specific type in order to use `age` property and `()` operation

---

UPD:

Swift is type-safe, so you cant do `myObj.age` if `myObj` is not from `NSObject` and haven't specific type. In you example Dog and Person haven't any similarities, so it's unlogic to cast them in one part.
If the would have something similarities, then you could create protocol and cast to it. Example below:

```
protocol Aged {
    var age: Int {get set}
    init()
}

class Person: Aged {
    var age: Int = 1

    //somehow this is critical
    required init () {
    }
}

class Dog: Aged {
    var age: Int =  5
    var color:String = "Blue"

    //somehow this is critical
    required init () {
    }
}

var hash2: [String: Any] = ["dog":Dog.self, "person":Person.self] // needed for real-world usage
if let t2 = hash2["person"] as? Aged.Type { 
    let p3 = t2() 
    println(p3.age)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you won't know what to cast it to in this portion of the code at run-time. It could just as easily have been a "dog" that was passed in via a string...You could have an "if let..." for every combination hard-coded in your codebase but that's not really extensible.

Comment: The particular case I am trying to emulate is objectiveC/Cocoa for reusing expensive NSView resources in a table-like view: `- (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

Comment: But dog haven't age. So it wont have any logic to cast. But you could create protocol and cast to it.

Comment: You are right - dog haven't age. I suppose that the common protocol should suffice for most situations because you should be trying to use the returned object instance in the same way in this corner of your codebase.

Comment: I updated my answer. And for your case - (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier you if-let will cast to NSView, but it could be any class that inherit NSView.